# DAGs are Intermittently unable to read files from `data/` in the GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I'm porting over some DAGs from a Composer 1/Airflow 1 instance that were originally moved over from a standalone Airflow 1.0 cluster, with code to load the specific config file as follows, towards the beginning of the file (after imports, but before I create my DAG):

```python
with open(SELLER_CONFIG_FILE, "r", encoding="utf8") as config_file:
```

`SELLER_CONFIG_FILE` is stored in `dags/config/__init__.py`, and looks as such:

```py
SELLER_CONFIG_FILE = os.getenv(
  "FORKLIFT__SELLER_CONFIG_FILE",
  os.path.join(FORKLIFT_REPO, "dag_conf", "seller_addresses.yaml"),
)
```

and `FORKLIFT_REPO` is set as an environment variable in Composer to `/home/airflow/gcs/data`. In a Composer 1/Airflow 1 cluster, this worked fine, but upon moving to Airflow 2, I'm getting intermittent messages of the type:

```traceback
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/daily_write_truncate_replication.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/daily_write_truncate_replication.py", line 21, in <module>
    replications = read_yaml_config(REPLICATIONS_CONFIG_FILE)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/utils/schema.py", line 23, in read_yaml_config
    with open(input_file, "r", encoding="UTF8") as y:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/airflow/gcs/data/replications.yaml'
```

As I mentioned, it's intermittent, with certain DAGs loading some of the time, some of them loading all of the time, and sometimes 25+ errors, with no real discernible pattern. It seems like there's a race condition which prevents the GCS data from being copied over locally before the DAG attempts to read them, and putting a `sleep(10)` statement before loading the config file(s) doesn't resolve the problem. Does anyone have any ideas/tips/tricks? There are several dozen of these config files.

Comment: If ever you can try contacting [gcp support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) to let them check your setup since this is an intermittent issue. This is if you have an existing free trial or premium support.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that according to [The Google Cloud Composer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/cloud-storage), everything the webserver needs to parse a DAG should be in the `dags/` folder, and nowhere else:

> To avoid a webserver error, make sure that data the webserver needs to parse a DAG (not run) is available in the dags/ folder. Otherwise, the webserver can't access the data or load the Airflow web interface.

Moving the configuration to `dags/config` in the GCS bucket and setting the `$FORKLIFT_REPO` environment variable appropriately solved the intermittent loading issue.